# How to 301 redirect when have two .htaccess files

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to enable a 301 redirect on my site cornwallcats.co.uk

I seem to have two .htaccess files in my root directory. One shows following and appears as a .txt file:

```
AddHandler x-mapp-php6 .html .htm

RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://www.cornwallcats.co.uk [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://cornwallcats.co.uk [L,R=301]
```

The other only shows (and has no filetype?):

```
AddHandler x-mapp-php6 .html .htm
```

Any help as to which .htaccess file I should edit  would be really helpful!

Thanks

Comment: You can't have two files with the same name. Which one is called `.htaccess` and which is called something else?

Comment: you can't have two different files with the same name in a directory. that's just not permitted. only ONE will be the actual .htaccess, and the other might be something like `.htaccess[space]` or even `.htaccess.txt`

Comment: Sorry the first file is .htaccess.txt, the second simply .htaccess

Is the first one not doing anything? If so, does the second part of the code need to be moved to the second file?

Comment: @Arron - yes, the second part of the code needs to be moved to the second file. There is no such thing as `.htaccess.txt`... `.htaccess` ***is*** the file extension.

Answer (score 0):

Transfer the contents of `.htaccess.txt` to `.htaccess` and then delete the file named `.htaccess.txt`.

If you want to add 301 redirect directives to your .htaccess file, you need to add them after

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Comment: What is the stuff that is already after the RewriteEngine On. I don't understand what that code is doing currently? Thanks!

Comment: If the file name is not `.htaccess` it does nothing

Comment: @Arron - the directive ensures that if someone points a browser at the site and they include a `www.` at the beginning of the URI, the `www.` will be removed.

Comment: So I already have a 301 redirect in place?? Doesn't seem to work even in a .htaccess file!

Comment: Didn't you have the 301 redirect in the (incorrectly named) .htaccess.txt instead of in the (correctly named) .htaccess?